# How to extract certain data using Perl from a file?

Tags: json, perl

I have data that needs to be extracted from a file, the lines I need for the moment are name,location and host. This is example of the extract. How would I go about getting these lines into a separate file? I have the Original file and the new file i want to create as the input/output file, there are thousands of devices contained within the output file and they are all the same formatting as in my example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

#names of files to be input output

my $inputfile = "/home/nmis/nmis_export.csv";
my $outputfile = "/home/nmis/nmis_data.csv";
open(INPUT,'<',$inputfile) or die $!;
open(OUTPUT, '>',$outputfile) or die $!;
my @data = <INPUT>;
close INPUT;
my $line="";
foreach $line (@data)
{
```

======Sample Extract=======

```
    **"group" : "NMIS8",
         "host" : "1.2.3.4",
         "location" : "WATERLOO",
         "max_msg_size" : 1472,
         "max_repetitions" : 0,
         "model" : "automatic",
         "netType" : "lan",
         "ping" : 1,
         "polling_policy" : "default",
         "port" : 161,
         "rancid" : 0,
         "roleType" : "access",
         "serviceStatus" : "Production",
         "services" : null,
         "threshold" : 1,
         "timezone" : 0,
         "version" : "snmpv2c",
         "webserver" : 0
      },
      "lastupdate" : 1616690858,
      "name" : "test",
      "overrides" : {}
},
   {
      "activated" : {
         "NMIS" : 1
      },
      "addresses" : [],
      "aliases" : [],
      "configuration" : {
         "Stratum" : 3,
         "active" : 1,
         "businessService" : "",
         "calls" : 0,
         "cbqos" : "none",
         "collect" : 0,
         "community" : "public",
         "depend" : [
            "N/A"
         ],
         "group" : "NMIS8",
         "host" : "1.2.3.5",
         "location" : "WATERLOO",
         "max_msg_size" : 1472,
         "max_repetitions" : 0,
         "model" : "automatic",
         "netType" : "lan",
         "ping" : 1,
         "polling_policy" : "default",
         "port" : 161,
         "rancid" : 0,
         "roleType" : "access",
         "serviceStatus" : "Production",
         "services" : null,
         "threshold" : 1,
         "timezone" : 0,
         "version" : "snmpv2c",
         "webserver" : 0
      },
      "lastupdate" : 1616690858,
      "name" : "test2",
      "overrides" : {}
   },**
```

Comment: Is the file you're providing JSON? It looks like.

Comment: yep it is - so i need to parse the data

Comment: I would not use Perl for this, I would use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: Can you please [update the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67726957/edit) to include the **exact** contents of your input file? I think @user157251's solution assumes you have an array of JSON objects, but your current sample doesn't actually include an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for this not Perl. You just need to query a JSON document. That's what jq is for. You can [see an example here](https://jqplay.org/s/yu4iUfkI0t)

The jq query I created is this one,

```
.[] | {name: .name, group: .configuration.group, location: .configuration.location}
```

This breaks down into

```
.[] # iterate over the array
  | # create a filter to send it to
  {  # that produces an object with the bellow key/values
    .name,
    group: .configuration.group,
    location: .configuration.location
  }
```

It provides an output like this,

```
{
  "name": "test2",
  "group": "NMIS8",
  "location": "WATERLOO"
}
{
  "name": "test2",
  "group": "NMIS8",
  "location": "WATERLOO"
}
```

You can use this to generate a csv

```sh
jq -R '.[] | [.name, .configuration.group, .configuration.location] | @csv' ./file.json
```

Or this to generate a csv with a header,

```
jq -R '["name","group","location"], (.[] | [.name, .configuration.group, .configuration.location]) | @csv' ./file.json
```

Comment: Would there be a way to put this into a CSV with a header of name,group, location?

What im really after is something like
name,group,location as the header and the info of test2, NMIS8,WATERLOO below

Comment: Great, i got JQ installed, im not familiar with how to use it, how do I add this in a script that i can run with a cron job? Essentially i need to specify the file im running it from and tell it to use jq. Input and output are at the original post.

Comment: I gave you the command above to run in the update. That's it. All it takes is `jq -R '["name","group","location"], (.[] | [.name, .configuration.group, .configuration.location]) | @csv' ./file.json`. Just redirect that to a new csv. `> my.csv` or whatever `jq -R '["name","group","location"], (.[] | [.name, .configuration.group, .configuration.location]) | @csv' ./file.json > my.csv`

Comment: yes, but how do i insert that command into my current script without getting a syntax error

Comment: Actually ran the command and getting
jq: error (at ./nmis_export.csv:80996): Cannot iterate over string ("         \...)
jq: error (at ./nmis_export.csv:80997): Cannot iterate over string ("      },")

Comment: No idea what you're doing, or what you're wanting to do. Take a look at the link I provided all of these commands will work with that. I'm also not sure what exactly you're doing with Perl. I took it that you just wanted to make a csv file from a JSON. I showed you how to do it without perl.

Comment: I tweaked the command a lil and is now working:  jq -r '["name","host","Stratum"], (.[] | [.name, .configuration.host, .configuration.Stratum])' nmis_export.csv > test.csv Need to figure out how to automate this ina  script now :)

Answer (score 3):

As what you have there is JSON, you should parse it with a JSON parser. [JSON::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/JSON-PP/lib/JSON/PP.pm) is part of the standard Perl distribution. If you want something faster, you could install something else from CPAN.

**Update:** I included a link to [JSON::PP](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/JSON-PP/lib/JSON/PP.pm) in my answer. Did you follow that link? If you did, you would have seen the documentation for the module. That has more information about how to use the module than I could include in an answer on SO.

But it's possible that you need a little more high-level information. The documentation says this:

> JSON::PP is a pure perl JSON decoder/encoder

But perhaps you don't know what that means. So here's a primer.

JSON is a text format for storing complex data structures. The format was initially used in Javascript (the acronym stands for "JavaScript Object Notation") but it is now a standard that is used across pretty much all programming languages.

You rarely want to actually deal with JSON in a program. A JSON document is just text and manipulating that would require some complex regular expressions. When dealing with JSON, the usual approach is to "decode" the JSON into a data structure inside your program. You can then manipulate the data structure however you want before (optionally) "encoding" the data structure back into JSON so you can write it to an output file (in your case, you don't need to do that as you want your output as CSV).

So there are pretty much only two things that a Perl JSON library needs to do:

1. Take some JSON text and decode it into a Perl data structure
2. Take a Perl data structure and encode it into JSON text

If you look at the [JSON::PP documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/JSON-PP/lib/JSON/PP.pm) you'll see that it contains two functions, `encode_json()` and `decode_json()` which do what I describe above. There's also an OO interface, but let's not overcomplicate things too quickly.

So your program now needs to have the following steps:

1. Read the JSON from the input file
2. Decode the JSON into a Perl data structure
3. Walk the Perl data structure to extract the items that you need
4. Write the required items into your output file (for which [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) will be useful

Having said all that, it really does seem to me that the [`jq` solution suggested by user157251](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67728007/7231) is a much better idea.

Comment: Thanks! How would you tie that in the code? use JSON::PP then how would i use that to extract the fields i need to the output, sorry kinda new new to scripting.

Comment: @Calarian If you want to use Perl, you need to learn Perl; just asking people on StackOverflow to write your code is not going to cut it. JSON::PP's `decode_json` returns a reference; you are expected to know what to do with it.

Comment: @Calarian: I'm afraid Dada is correct. If you need some Perl written, you either need to take the time to learn Perl or you need to hire someone who already knows Perl. However, I've added some more information to my answer that might help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `JSON` distribution for this. Read the entire file in one fell swoop to put the entire JSON string into a scalar (as opposed to putting it into an array and iterating over it), then simply decode the string into a Perl data structure:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use JSON;

my $file = 'file.json';

my $json_string;

{
    local $/;              # Locally reset line endings to nothing

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open file $file!: $!";

    $json_string = <$fh>;  # Slurp in the entire file
}

my $perl_data_structure = decode_json $json_string;
```